# Not able to return sum of array elements

Tags: javascript, protractor

My function adds the sum of currency values of an array after adding the sum i can't able to return the sum   console.log("total array sum", + array_sum);
this is not giving any reult on console[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1tn3.png)

```js
function sumOfMonthsFullSeason(){
  var promises = [];
  var array_sum = 0;
  for(var month_index = 6; month_index <= 25 ; month_index++){
    const elm_xpath = utils.getXpathForSubCategory(chosen_season_index, month_index);
    promises.push(element(by.xpath(elm_xpath)).getText());
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(function(data){
    if (data != NaN){
      for(var i = 0; i <=data.length; i++){
        var array = parseFloat(data[i].replace(/[^?\d+(\.\d+)?]/g, ''));
        array_sum += array;
        console.log("sum of all months", + array_sum);
      }
      console.log("total array sum", + array_sum);
      return array_sum;
    }else{
      return array_sum = 0;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: I also added the result of my console in the above image

Comment: You need to get rid of the javascript error before worrying about correct output. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`. My guess is that data[i] is undefined on the last iteration because your loop goes 1 element too far because of `i <= data.length` which should probably just be `i < data.length`.

Comment: it is  warning it's expecting a return promise that is why i called this return array_sum; but it is not going to that step  and if return the same at  return array_sum += array; . it is giving me only first value of the array

Comment: yes you are right that is what the issue i guess it works fine now Thank you  – csmckelvey

Comment: When I try a console.log like yours, I get weird behaviors. I either put the + sign or the comma, not both!